# How to remove the decorator visibility within the ComboBox control from MaterialDesignXamlToolkit?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, material-design-in-xaml

How to remove the decorator visibility within the `ComboBox` control from `MaterialDesignXamlToolkit`?

Example: I want to get from this:

[image: ComboBox with underline.]

to this:

[image: Expected: ComboBox without underline.]

I've tried to set the textfield decoration visibility to hidden:

```
materialDesign:TextFieldAssist.DecorationVisibility="Hidden"
```

However, this don't remove the underline decoration.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two different decorations that you see in your `ComboBox`.

- There is an `Underline` with different effects that can be hidden using this attached property:

  ```
  materialDesign:TextFieldAssist.DecorationVisibility="Hidden"
  ```

  You can see this underline in the [default control style on GitHub](https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/blob/ff269f442e482ebc9b241e92a16f3cf32252e208/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.ComboBox.xaml#L505).
- The `ComboBox` has a [border on the bottom](https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/blob/ff269f442e482ebc9b241e92a16f3cf32252e208/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.ComboBox.xaml#L971) that is not affected by the attached property.

  ```
  <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0 0 0 1"/>
  ```

Since you have already deactivated the underline, you probably want to remove the border. The easiest way to do this is to set the `BorderThickness` completely on your `ComboBox`.

```
<ComboBox materialDesign:TextFieldAssist.DecorationVisibility="Hidden"
          BorderThickness="0">
```

You can of course move this out to a reusable style if you want to.

```
<Style x:Key="MyComboBoxStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ComboBox}}">
   <Setter Property="materialDesign:TextFieldAssist.DecorationVisibility" Value="Hidden"/>
   <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
</Style>
```

```
<ComboBox Style="{StaticResource MyComboBoxStyle}">
```

Remove the `x:Key` if you want to make the style *implicit* which is applied to all `ComboBox`es in scope.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for.